# GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync errors in .net 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I am upgrading a .net core 2.2 app to .net 6.

I have an api to register users, which then sends a email confirmation.
I'm generating the confirmation code like this, however it errors with the message below.

Any ideas

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

error thrown:

```
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbSecret, UInt32 cbSecret, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy, Boolean fLocalMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapi(ISecret secret, Boolean protectToLocalMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.EncryptIfNecessary(IXmlEncryptor encryptor, XElement element)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1.GenerateAsync(String purpose, UserManager`1 manager, TUser user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that i needed the last line (in program.cs):

```
 IdentityBuilder b = builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    opt.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
                    opt.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;

                }
            );
```

Comment: How is anyone meant to know that? Thanks a lot. I have been stuck on this for about 2 weeks now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() method
Is there anything like this fix.